# tried to change home folder location, now can't log in

Tags: partitioning, login, files, home-directory

So obviously this is my first interaction with Linux. Finally got Ubuntu installed and I tried to move my home folder to another partition and followed the instructions here: http://www.maketecheasier.com/move-home-folder-ubuntu

Everything went smooth except `sudo mount -a` command, both times it told me that device is already mounted or something. So as stupid as I am I just tried to restart the computer to see what happens. Sure enough now I can not log in to my account...

I am now on the guest account, any way I could get this fixed? Help please....

So the media directory that supposedly got created by following this tutorial is still there, but I can't see the partition I was trying to move the home folder on in the explorer anymore. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that it's ntfs filesystem and when I tried to move the home directory there something got mixed up? I have no problem deleting that partition and creating a new one, it's a new laptop with no documents on it anyway.

Comment: You probably can't login to your desktop because you don't have access to your home directory. use Ctrl+alt+f1, log in with your user. Then you should be able to do "sudo adduser tempuser", then do "sudo adduser tempuser sudo". You'll now have a user "tempuser" that has sudo access. You can use this to make it easier to fix your primary user.

Comment: I actually ended up doing that. Lucky I had my home folder backup, so I was able to copy back my home folder backup for my user. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're like me: a Windows Guru who has switched to the dark side...  ;)

**In a nutshell:**

The *easiest* thing to do, is just start again, but when you're on the "Installation type" screen, don't choose "Alongside windows XXX" but "Something else".
Then choose the partition/disk where you want to install Ubuntu itself and use mount point "/" for that.  *For your home folder* just take the secondary partition/disk and use "/home" as a mount point.

**The long version**

I've been using Ubuntu for nearly a year now, so I wouldn't do what you just did *any more*.  Forget that you're a guru!  You're a *newbie* (I still am after nearly a year)! 
Read all the following articles to help you become an Ubuntu Guru:
[Switching from Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingFromWindows)

Read everything that applies to you from:
[Ubuntu Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation)

And also read:
[File Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/)